# How to keep one layout over another layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my xml I want to keep one layout over another layout.

I have progress Bar and try again Textview in same place I am doing visible and invisible Textview and Progressbar programatically, so I want keep Progressbar over try again button, but I am unable to do this.

I have searched from google that we can do using Frame layout but its not working.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/tesco_blue"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_18"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_18"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_12"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_18">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/securebarcode_error_layout_variant_a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_56"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_56"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <android.support.v4.widget.Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_40" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/errortitle"
            style="@style/Typeface.Body.Bold.White"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="4sp"
            tools:text="@string/pwp_network_error" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/errordesc"
            style="@style/Typeface.Body.White"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_12"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
            tools:text="@string/pwp_network_error_description" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            >
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pwp_progressbarlayout_variant_a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"


            android:visibility="visible"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/cl_48"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/cl_48"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_12"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_12"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress_bar"/>
        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/try_again"
            style="@style/Typeface.Body.Bold.HighlightBlue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/error_button_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/cl_48"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/cl_48"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_12"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_12"
            android:text="@string/Tryagain"
            android:textColor="@color/fdv_pending_state_color" />


        <android.support.v4.widget.Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_40" />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use `FrameLayout` its there for a reason.

Comment: You need to explain what "its not working" means: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @KaranMer is right. You can also use `Relative Layout` if you just want to play with `ProgressBar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your Layout as below - `Relative Layout` can do the trick

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/tesco_blue"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_18"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_18"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_12"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_18">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/securebarcode_error_layout_variant_a"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_56"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_56"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:visibility="visible">

            <android.support.v4.widget.Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_40" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/errortitle"
                style="@style/Typeface.Body.Bold.White"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="4sp"
                tools:text="@string/pwp_network_error" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/errordesc"
                style="@style/Typeface.Body.White"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_12"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
                tools:text="@string/pwp_network_error_description" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/try_again"
                style="@style/Typeface.Body.Bold.HighlightBlue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/error_button_background"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/cl_48"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/cl_48"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_12"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_12"
                android:text="@string/Tryagain"
                android:textColor="@color/fdv_pending_state_color" />


            <android.support.v4.widget.Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_40" />


        </LinearLayout>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/pwp_progressbarlayout_variant_a"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress_bar"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You can simply use constraint layout in your case as basically its
   from the family of frame layout , you can implement the code below.just take your root layout as ConstraintLayout

   ```
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/try_again"
       style="@style/Typeface.Body.Bold.HighlightBlue"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
       android:background="@drawable/error_button_background"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:paddingLeft="@dimen/cl_48"
       android:paddingRight="@dimen/cl_48"
       android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_12"
       android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_12"
       android:text="@string/Tryagain"
       android:textColor="@color/fdv_pending_state_color" />

   <ProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/pwp_progressbarlayout_variant_a"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/try_again"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/try_again"
       app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/try_again"
       app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/try_again"
       android:visibility="visible"
       android:paddingLeft="@dimen/cl_48"
       android:paddingRight="@dimen/cl_48"
       android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_12"
       android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_12"
       android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress_bar"/>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You have to move your `try_again` TextView to inside of FrameLayout so the your Progressbar will show on TextView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/tesco_blue"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_18"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_18"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_12"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_18">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/securebarcode_error_layout_variant_a"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_56"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_56"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:visibility="visible">

    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_40" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/errortitle"
        style="@style/Typeface.Body.Bold.White"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="4sp"
        tools:text="@string/pwp_network_error" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/errordesc"
        style="@style/Typeface.Body.White"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_12"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
        tools:text="@string/pwp_network_error_description" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pwp_progressbarlayout_variant_a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress_bar"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/cl_48"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_12"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/cl_48"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_12"
            android:visibility="visible" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/try_again"
            style="@style/Typeface.Body.Bold.HighlightBlue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/error_button_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/cl_48"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_12"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/cl_48"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_12"
            android:text="@string/Tryagain"
            android:textColor="@color/fdv_pending_state_color" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_40" />
```

Here it is the image what you want.

[image]

Comment: Sorry </LinearLayout> closing tag is missing in the end of the layout.